# How to show all methods of a class without ancestors methods in ruby?

Tags: ruby

To show all methods defined by a particular class, but without methods that are defined in ancestors classes, I'm writing like this.

```
foo.methods - foo.class.superclass.methods
```

Is there better way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to include overridden methods?

Comment: yes, and I assured now that `Class.instance_methods(false)` include also overridden methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get instance methods with the following:

```
foo.class.instance_methods(false)
```

as documented in http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods.

The documentation for the parameter uses the term "superclasses" in describing what is included if the parameter is truthy, but based on my testing I believe all ancestor-provided methods are excluded/included based on this value, not just those from superclasses.